# Determining if a capacitor will charge or discharge based on voltage

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, voltage, capacitance, batteries

[image: image of the RC circuit]

The question also says that the voltage of the battery is 12 V. We're supposed to determine if the capacitor is charging or discharging or neither. I'm just not sure how to use the voltages given to decide if it's charging or not, because part 2 of this same qs has the same circuit with initial $\Delta V_c = 0V$ and the answer says that the capacitor is charging, but I'm not sure again how we reached that conclusion.

Comment: If the initial voltage on the capacitor is $0$, then it will charge. However, if it is 6 V, it cannot be answered without knowing the value of the resistors.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the value of the resistors that appear in the circuit. Let $R_1$ be the resistor on the left side in series with the battery, and $R_2$ the other one in the middle of the circuit.

Answering this requires knowing how a capacitor behaves, which in general can be known by studying a differential equation. However, since this a DC circuit, it can be simplified as follows: **the state of a capacitor will reach an equilibrium point, in which it will have a constant voltage and no current flow, thus, behaving as an open circuit**.

Therefore, what we can do is to look for the final voltage on the capacitor in equilibrium. This is just computing the voltage across the capacitor as it was an open circuit in which there is no current flow, that is
$$
\Delta V_C (\text{final}) = \dfrac{R_2 V_{\text{Battery}}}{R_1 + R_2}\ .
$$

Therefore, the capacitor will charge if
$$
\dfrac{R_2 V_{\text{Battery}}}{R_1 + R_2} \gt \Delta V_C (\text{initial})\ ,
$$
and discharge otherwise. If the initial voltage across the capacitor is zero, then it will always charge, but if it is 6 V, the answer will depend on the values of the resistors and the battery.